# Apache Reverse Proxy https to http? does SSL certificate is mandatory

Tags: apache, server, config, reverse-proxy

Hi I have been working on setting up my webserver. We have the company domain https://www.company.com which is already with https, which we are unable to get SSL certificates. I wanted to make use this domain and deploy my app (http) by adding https//www.company.com/myapp this myapp and map this url to the http app which is deployed.

I am using the configuration shown below for your reference. I have a doubt only if we get SSL only we progress or their is some way to map this domain to my app running on port 8000.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName company.com
ServerAlias www.company.com

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8000/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8000/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use HTTP, use port 80 instead of 443. you can also use both separately for HTTP and HTTPS connection.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName company.com
ServerAlias www.company.com

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8000/

RewriteEngine On
..................
 As per server requirements
..................

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName company.com
ServerAlias www.company.com

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8000/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8000/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```